# Laravel - Ambiguous Column Name when using Offset

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, eloquent

I'm using `offset` and `limit` to paginate the results returned via an API. I'm querying from 2 tables named `ssc` and `users`, both of them having a column named `id` (primary key). The database driver is *Microsoft SQL Server*.

When calling the below query (where `$offset = 2` and `$limit = 25`):

```
$cc = DB::table('ssc')->select('ssc.*','u.name')
      ->join('users AS u','ssc.supervisor_code','=','u.user_code')
      ->where('ssc.status','=',1)
      ->offset($offset)
      ->limit($limit)
      ->orderBy($orderby,$order)
      ->get();
```

I'm getting the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Ambiguous column name 'id'.

The generated query by Laravel (Eloquent) from the above code:

```
select * 
from (
    select [ssc].*, 
        [u].[name], 
        row_number() over (order by [id] asc) as row_num 
    from [ssc] 
    inner join [users] as [u] on [ssc].[supervisor_code] = [u].[user_code] 
    where [ssc].[status] = 1
) as temp_table
where row_num between 26 and 50
```

As you can see above, the ambiguous column is `[id]` in the `order by`.

How can I control which table & column combination to use in offset/limit? Checking the [Laravel API](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_offset) shows that there's no extra parameters for both functions.

Comment: we cab't really help you since we dont know how the variable `$orderBy` is populated and what are it's possible values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @N69S's comment, the issue was with the `$orderBy` variable being defined as `id` only, making it ambiguous between `ssc` and `u`. Switching it to `u.id` solved the issue.